# cannot find symbol "var" in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, java-10

Whenever I try to run my application from Intellij Idea I get the following error..

If I build the application via Maven it works fine.

Take a look at my module settings the JDK is v10, the language is v10 as well for both the project and module.

Any idea why this would be happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hopefully, the IntelliJ version in use is compatible with Java-10. Strange though, that the IntelliJ logs read *javac 10.0.1 was used to compile java sources* and it still fails to identify `var` keyword. What does the code in question look like?

Answer (score 17):

I have no idea how this ever got set wrong but I had the Java compiler bytecode version settings set wrong in the IDE preferences...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Mine was somehow changed to 9 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯